# Loop just taking into account the first element of a multiple condition

Tags: r

I am running this loop to detect some specific character elements of a data frame column to rewrite them. I want to find all elements matching one of theese patterns `'H309'` or `'H2020'`, and rewrite them.

All of the characters of this column follow this pattern:

`coord;number;strand;id;rate;name;tissue`

While those having `H309`or `H2020` as name present this other pattern:

`coord;rate;number;id;strand;name`

As an example:

```
seqnames                                          Score

coord1;nb1;strand1;id1;rate1;X77I;bladder           1
coord2;nb2;strand2;id2;rate2;YH7;bone               2
coord3;rate3;nb3;id3;strand3;H309                   3
coord4;nb4;strand4;id4;rate4;LÑB;brain              4
coord5;rate5;nb5;id5;strand5;H2020                  5
.                                                   .
.                                                   .
.                                                   .
.                                                   .
```

So, I want theese characters to follow the pattern of the rest, what I've tryed doing this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df){
if (grepl("H309", df$seqnames[i]) == TRUE || grepl("H2020", df$seqnames[i]) == TRUE){
    a = str_split(df$seqnames[i], ";")
    df$seqnames[i] <- paste(a[[1]][1], a[[1]][3], a[[1]][5], a[[1]][4], a[[1]][2],a[[1]][[6]],'Lung', sep=';')
  }
}
```

The problem is that the loop is only working whith `H309` elements, and not with `H2020` ones.

So now, `H309` samples present also this pattern: `coord;number;strand;id;rate;name;tissue`

While `H2020` still present the other pattern: `coord;rate;number;id;strand;name`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not `grepl("H309|H2020", etc)`?

Comment: Yes, that has worked! Thanks! But do you know why did not work my code?

Comment: The `== TRUE` is too much. `grepl` already returns a logical value, there is no need for that comparison. Try to remove it and see if itworks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves the question's problem.
It creates an index `i` with the patterns' matches. Though I use `grepl`,the index doesn't need to be a logical index, it will never be used for `if(.)` statements.
Then, it splits the corresponding strings by `';'` and `lapply`'s an anonymous function to reorder each of those vectors.

```
i <- grepl("H309|H2020", df$seqnames)

inx_order <- c(1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6)

a <- stringr::str_split(df$seqnames[i], ";")
df$seqnames[i] <- lapply(a, function(x){
  x <- paste(x[inx_order], collapse = ';')
  paste(x, 'Lung', sep = ';')
})

df
#                                   seqnames Score
#1 coord1;nb1;strand1;id1;rate1;X77I;bladder     1
#2     coord2;nb2;strand2;id2;rate2;YH7;bone     2
#3    coord3;nb3;strand3;id3;rate3;H309;Lung     3
#4    coord4;nb4;strand4;id4;rate4;LÑB;brain     4
#5   coord5;nb5;strand5;id5;rate5;H2020;Lung     5
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
seqnames                                          Score
coord1;nb1;strand1;id1;rate1;X77I;bladder           1
coord2;nb2;strand2;id2;rate2;YH7;bone               2
coord3;rate3;nb3;id3;strand3;H309                   3
coord4;nb4;strand4;id4;rate4;LÑB;brain              4
coord5;rate5;nb5;id5;strand5;H2020                  5
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(text = "seqnames                                          Score
coord1;nb1;strand1;id1;rate1;X77I;bladder           1
coord2;nb2;strand2;id2;rate2;YH7;bone               2
coord3;rate3;nb3;id3;strand3;H309                   3
coord4;nb4;strand4;id4;rate4;LÑB;brain              4
coord5;rate5;nb5;id5;strand5;H2020                  5", header = TRUE)


indx <- grep("H(\\d+)$", df$seqnames) 

df$seqnames[indx] <- paste0(df$seqnames[indx], ";Lung")

changes <-  strsplit(df$seqnames[indx], ";")
changes <- lapply(changes, FUN = "[", c(1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6, 7)) # rearrange

changes <- sapply(changes, paste0, collapse = ";") # glue the splited text together

df$seqnames[indx] <- changes

df
                                   seqnames   Score
1 coord1;nb1;strand1;id1;rate1;X77I;bladder     1
2     coord2;nb2;strand2;id2;rate2;YH7;bone     2
3    coord3;nb3;strand3;id3;rate3;H309;Lung     3
4    coord4;nb4;strand4;id4;rate4;LÑB;brain     4
5   coord5;nb5;strand5;id5;rate5;H2020;Lung     5
```